# How does Victoria get convicted if Emily is still deemed a nutjob?

Tags: plot-explanation, side-effects

In the movie Side Effects, at the end, Victoria is arrested for Insider Trading and planning the Murder. The murder however is committed by Emily, whose end judgement it so go back to the mental ward. If that is the case Emily is still deemed a nutjob. Agreed that Double Jeopardy prevents her from going to trial one more time so as a hack they put her in the Mental ward.

From Victoria's standpoint, this becomes an advantage because she could always plea that one can never conspire and plan anything with a mentally troubled person. She might lose her license as a practitioner but can't be held prisoner for anything unless Emily is deemed NOT a nut-case.

Am I missing something here? Did I get it wrong?

Comment: Wasn't she *caught admitting to it?* It's been a while since I've seen the movie so I can't recall. That said, I think the movie ends with her being arrested, not convicted. The prosecutor could deem that they don't have a case.

Answer (score 1):

Emily goes with a wire to Victoria's house. Victoria says enough to form proof that she used a person (although mentally unstable) to do things that would allow for her to trade favorably in the stock market.

Messing around with the stock market and making yourself money is a crime regardless of how you did it. It could be through a sane person, insider trading like Martin did, or using an unstable person to say/do certain things.

The end game is that Victoria performed an illegal act of making money off the market and that case would still hold on her regardless of Emily's condition.